# iPhone does not ring through speaker with headphones connected

Tags: iphone, audio, bluetooth, headphones, speakers

iPhone 11, iOS 14.1.

When the Bluetooth headphones are connected, the phone only rings through them, which means if I take the headphones off I can't hear the phone ring.

I'm hard of hearing, so I keep the headphones connected so I can hear people on the phone. However, it's very uncomfortable and profoundly difficult to keep them on all day. How do I make the phone ring through the speaker (loudly) even when the headphones are connected?

Turning the headphones on and off as necessary is also not an option because it takes so long for them to sync with the phone that callers hang up thinking they have a dead line.

Comment: Is the physical silent switch turned on?

Comment: No, the physical silent switch is not turned on.